# Hazard function, survival function, and retention rate

Tags: survival, hazard

What is the difference between the hazard function, survival function, and retention rate in survival analysis?

Comment: What does your book say about these things?

Comment: I don't have a book. my professors are not fully explaining. is there a book you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hazard Function/Hazard Rate,say, $\lambda_i$:-** probability of life not survive in the $i^{th}$ time interval($t_i-t_{i-1}$).

**Survival Function,$S(t_i)$:-** probability of life survive upto $t_i$.

**Retention Rate,$1-\lambda_i$:-** probability of Life survive in $i_{th}$ time interval($t_i-t_{i-1}$).

*Relations:-*

Relation between hazard rate and retention rate remains same(**Retention Rate=1- Hazard Rate**)

But relation with Survival Function may differ, like in Kaplan-Meier method $S(t_i)=\prod_i (1-\lambda_i)$ and in Nelson-Aalen $S(t_i)=exp(-\sum_i\lambda_i)$

Answer (score 0):

Using testing light bulbs on a daily basis for example. (You count how many fail a day)

Hazard rate       ----  'Failures'/'number of current good bulbs' by day.

Survival rate     ----  Proportion of the ones the remain OK by day.

Retention rate    ----  1 - 'hazard rate'

Plot the rates v.s. time(days) you get the functions.